# How can I scrape this page with selenium and chromedriver in python language?

Tags: screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from the website “http://www.nmpa.gov.cn/” by using selenium and chromedriver. When I was running the code, chromedriver succeeded in inputing the url but couldn't load the page, displaying a blank page. I tried to switch the target website into google.com and succeeded in scraping. I concluded that the target website server detected selenium and refused sending back data. So how can I scrape the data from website with selenium and chromedriver in python language. I'm quite a Python beginner, thank you for your kind help in advance. Here is my simple code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
my_driver_path = r"C:\python chrome driver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=my_driver_path)
driver.get('http://www.nmpa.gov.cn/')
```

here is the photo of the issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIhsA.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is more on HTML than on Python.

If you check the source code of the page (you can do this by adding `print(driver.page_source)`, you will see that it contains a meta tag with the `http-equiv` attribute set to "refresh":

```html
<HTML><HEAD><title>NMPA</title></HEAD>
<body>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312"><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/WS04/CL2042/">
</HTML>
```

What this tag does is direct the browser to go to the given URL (`/WS04/CL2042/`, in a badly formatted attribute that the browser is luckily able to understand). So, **instead of scraping http://www.nmpa.gov.cn/, you have to scrape http://www.nmpa.gov.cn/WS04/CL2042/**.

If you change your code to access this other link, you will see that then you can get the whole page. You can either hard-code the new link or safely concatenate the first link with the "refresh" destination with a method like `urllib.parse.join()`: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin.